# Efficient way to extract and collect a random subsample of a generator in Julia

Tags: memory, iteration, julia, generator

Consider a generator in Julia that if collected will take a lot of memory

```
g=(x^2 for x=1:9999999999999999)
```

I want to take a random small subsample (Say 1%) of it, but I do not want to collect() the object because will take a lot of memory

Until now the trick I was using was this

```
temp=collect((( rand()>0.01 ? nothing : x ) for x in g))
random_sample= temp[temp.!=nothing]
```

But this is not efficient for generators with a lot of elements, collecting something with so many nothing elements doesnt seem right

Any idea is highly appreciated. I guess the trick is to be able to get random elements from the generator without having to allocate memory for all of it.

Thank you very much

Comment: [Reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator with `if` condition like this:

```
[v for v in g if rand() < 0.01]
```

or if you want a bit faster, but more verbose approach (I have hardcoded `0.01` and element type of `g` and I assume that your generator supports `length` - otherwise you can remove `sizehint!` line):

```
function collect_sample(g)
    r = Int[]
    sizehint!(r, round(Int, length(g) * 0.01))
    for v in g
        if rand() < 0.01
           push!(r, v)
        end
    end
    r
end
```

**EDIT**

Here you have examples of self avoiding sampler and reservoir sampler giving you fixed output size. The smaller fraction of the input you want to get the better it is to use self avoiding sampler:

```
function self_avoiding_sampler(source_size, ith, target_size)
    rng = 1:source_size
    idx = rand(rng)
    x1 = ith(idx)
    r = Vector{typeof(x1)}(undef, target_size)
    r[1] = x1
    s = Set{Int}(idx)
    sizehint!(s, target_size)
    for i = 2:target_size
        while idx in s
            idx = rand(rng)
        end
        @inbounds r[i] = ith(idx)
        push!(s, idx)
    end
    r
end

function reservoir_sampler(g, target_size)
    r = Vector{Int}(undef, target_size)
    for (i, v) in enumerate(g)
        if i <= target_size
            @inbounds r[i] = v
        else
            j = rand(1:i)
            if j < target_size
                @inbounds r[j] = v
            end
        end
    end
    r
end
```

Comment: This approach, however, is not guaranteed to take exactly the same number of items each time (e.g., about 1% of the items) (as implied in the question), but rather selects items such that each item has a 1% chance of being selected.

Comment: This was the algorithm used in the question so I assumed this should not change. I have only changed the approach to show that you do not have to collect the generator. If you want to have an exact size of the result there are several possible options depending on the nature of your input. Reservoir sampling is one option as indicated by @phg. In this case also simple self avoid sampling should be fast, but it requires indexing into a generator. I will add such an example in the answer.

Comment: That's a really elegant implementation of `reservoir_sampler`! No unintuitive divisions at all.