# Efficient Stratified Random Sampling in Julia

Tags: performance, julia, sampling

I am trying to write a little function to do stratified random sampling. That is, I have a vector of group membership for each element, and I want to select a single element (index) for each group. Thus, the input is the number of elements desired, and the group membership for each element. The output is a list of indices.

Here's the function I have:

```
function stratified_sample(n::Int64, groups::Array{Int64})

    # the output vector of indices
    ind = zeros(Int64, n)

    # first select n groups from the total set of possible groups
    group_samp = sample(unique(groups), n, replace = false)

    # cycle through the selected groups
    for i in 1:n
        # for each group, select one index whose group matches the current target group
        ind[i] = sample([1:length(groups)...][groups.==group_samp[i]], 1, replace = false)[1]
    end

    # return the indices
    return ind
end
```

When I run this code on a relatively large vector, for example, 1000 different groups and 40000 total entries, I get

```
julia> groups = sample(1:1000, 40000, replace = true)
40000-element Array{Int64,1}:
 221
 431
 222
 421
 714
 108
 751
 259
   ⋮
 199
 558
 317
 848
 271
 358

julia> @time stratified_sample(5, groups)
  0.022951 seconds (595.06 k allocations: 19.888 MiB)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 11590
 17057
 17529
 25103
 20651
```

And to compare this to normal random sampling of five elements from 40000 possible:

```
julia> @time sample(1:40000, 5, replace = false)
  0.000005 seconds (5 allocations: 608 bytes)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 38959
  5850
  3283
 19779
 30063
```

So my code is running nearly 50k times slower and using up 33k times more memory! What in world have I done wrong, and is there a way to speed up this code? My guess is the real slow down is happening in the subsetting step, i.e., `[1:length(groups)...][groups.==group_samp[i]]`, but I can't find a better solution.

I've searched endlessly for this function within standard Julia packages, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

---

**EDIT:** I've been able to speed it up a lot by just taking a random sample, and checking to see if it satisfies the requirement that there are n unique groups selected:

```
function stratified_sample_random(n::Int64, groups::Array{Int64}, group_probs::Array{Float32})
    ind = zeros(Int64, n)
    my_samp = []
    while true
        my_samp = wsample(1:length(groups), group_probs, n, replace = false)
        if length(unique(groups[my_samp])) == n
            break
        end
    end

    return my_samp

end
```

Here, `group_probs` is just a vector of sampling probabilities, where each group's elements have a total probability of 1/s, where s is the number of elements in that group. For example, if `groups = [1,1,1,1,2,3,3]` the the corresponding probabilities would be `group_probs = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1, 0.5, 0.5]`. This helps speed up the sampling by minimizing the probability of selecting multiple items of one group. Overall it works fairly well:

```
@time stratified_sample_random(5, groups, group_probs)
  0.000122 seconds (14 allocations: 1.328 KiB)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 32209
 10184
 30892
  4861
 30300
```

From a bit of experimenting, weighted sampling by probability is not necessarily faster than standard sample(), but this depends on how many unique groups and what the desired `n` value is.

Of course, there's no guarantee this function will randomly sample a unique set of objects, and it could cycle forever. My thought is to add a counter to the while loop, and if it's tried for something like 10000 times with no luck, then it will call the original `stratified_sample` function I presented, to ensure it returns a unique result. I don't love this solution, and there must be a more elegant and parsimonious approach, but it's definitely an improvement.

Comment: As an alternative, you could keep a one-element [reservoir sampler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56201391/1346276) per group (maintaining just the group sample and the already visited group elements), and run it over the data once. O(N) time, O(groups) space.

Comment: OK, I might have gotten that wrong. What about one reservoir for the chosen `n` groups, and a single-element reservoir per sampled group.

Comment: Have a look at https://mldatapatternjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation/targets.html#stratified

Comment: Thank for the suggestion to check out the ML sampling. As afar as I can tell though, these functions don't allow one to sample only a single item per group, which is what I need here.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `[1:length(groups)...]`, you are splatting and allocating a `40000` element array `n` times, you should avoid this. Here is a 33x faster version using a range `inds` instead. Knowing the real application, though, we could still come up with a way faster method.

```
function stratified_sample(n::Int64, groups::Array{Int64})

    # the output vector of indices
    ind = zeros(Int64, n)

    # first select n groups from the total set of possible groups
    group_samp = sample(unique(groups), n, replace = false)

    inds = 1:length(groups)
    # cycle through the selected groups
    for i in 1:n
        # for each group, select one index whose group matches the current target group
        ind[i] = sample(inds[groups.==group_samp[i]], 1, replace = false)[1]
    end

    # return the indices
    return ind
end
```

Comment: Also, `sample(..., 1)[1]` is probably equivalent to `rand(...)`

Comment: Thanks. That certainly speeds it up some. The application doesn't provide much more help I think -- I have a bunch of objects, some of which have a single type, some of which have multiple types. I'm taking a bunch of bootstrap sampled and want to apply a function to the random sample. I need to hold the number of objects fixed, so I can only select 1 type of each object per random sample, and want exactly n objects per bootstrap sample.